# Android - Go to new screen on button click

Tags: java, android

Followed a tutorial but doesnt seem to work on emulation.

MainActivity.java:

```
package b.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;


        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Activity2.java:

```
package b.myfirstapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="b.myfirstapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Activity2" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

There are no errors in the code, its just that when i emulate it it doesnt work, maybe ive coded it incorrectly, not too sure, it looks fine to me.

I'm new to android dev so im confused. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:** (For clearance purposes with comments properly inserted)

I think you are missing the call to `addListenerOnButton` in your `MainActivity` class, for example inside `onCreate` right after `setContentView...`.

Also, you should make it `private` since it's only going to be called from within this class.

Comment: You have to make a call to `addListenerOnButton`, so that the code inside is actually executed.

Comment: Add `addListenerOnButton();` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: You have to add it in the `MainActivity` NOT in `Activity2`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not called your addListenerOnButton method so you have not set onClick handler to your button.

Your onCreate should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton()
}
```